# PHP GET not retrieving value from URL with %20 (space) in it

Tags: php, forms, get

I'm trying to retrieve the "custom Phone" value from a form where the variables are being passed through a URL and then retrieved using the PHP Get method.

Here is the URL with the pass through variables:

http://domain.com/redirect.php?custom%20phone=555-555-5555&email=jk%40blackdiamondacademy%2ecom&from=jk%40blackdiamondacademy%2ecom&listname=fgxpressusa&meta_adtracking=&meta_message=1&meta_required=name%2cemail%2ccustom%20Phone&name=Jordan&submit=Submit&submit.x=121&submit.y=27

Here is the code on my landing page that has the Get PHP code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sale = PostAffTracker.createAction('lead');
sale.setOrderID('<?php echo $_GET['meta_message']; ?>');
sale.setProductID('<?php echo $_GET['unit']; ?>');
sale.setData1('<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>');
sale.setData2('<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>');
sale.setData3('<?php echo $_GET['custom%20phone']; ?>');
PostAffTracker.register();
</script>
```

The code retrieves the "name", and "email" but not the "custom%20phone". I tried putting 'custom phone' as the get value as well as 'custom+phone' and still it doesn't retrieve it.

The issue seems to be the space in the value from my web form ("custom Phone") that is being passed through the URL as "custom%20phone".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: most likely your form's input name is `name='custom phone'` and should be `name='custom_phone`

Comment: global rule....

variables cannot contain space. please change custom phone into custom_phone or customPhone. for this you must probably change name of field in the form getting submitted.

Comment: its not valid to have a space in the form name element:  ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: from http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php ->`Note: Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example <input name="a.b" /> becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"].`. So try `$_GET['custom_phone'];`, although it would be better to fix this on the form element side.

Comment: Thanks guys! I actually figured the same solution out through trial and error and posted the answer before I saw all these comments. Thanks again!

Comment: Space is not allowed in variable!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer to my own question through trial and error.

The PHP GET method translates %20 as an underscore so I put:

```
<?php echo $_GET['custom_phone']; ?>
```

Works perfect!

Comment: its still better to fix the form and not use a space

Comment: you should try to avoid spaces while defining a variable to store some value. it would be better if you remove all of the unwanted spaces in your form and replace them with either _(underscore) or something better. Thanks...